# Bounded projector in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am facing the following exercise in functional analysis.

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P$ a bounded projector. We define the subspaces  $M=\operatorname{im}P$ and $N=\operatorname{im}(I-P)^\perp$. Show that $$\require{amsmath,mathtools} \alpha=\inf_{m\in M\setminus\{0\}}\sup_{n\in N\setminus\{0\}}\frac{|\langle m,n\rangle|}{||m|| ||n||}>0.$$

I know that $M$ and $N$ are closed since $P$ is bounded and that we can write $N=(\operatorname{ker} P)^\perp$. Now let $m=Pu$ with $u\not\in \operatorname{ker} P$ and $n\in N$, I don't see how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

(By the way, is there any general intuition to this "inf-sup"-condition?)

Comment: At least, we can say that $\inf \cdots >0$ means $\exists \epsilon >0, \forall \cdots > \epsilon$.

Comment: Is there something wrong about my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is a completely different approach. By writing $H=M\oplus M^\perp$, we can see the elements of $B(H)$ as $2\times 2$ block matrices. The fact that $P$ is an idempotent with range $M$ gives us
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} I&B\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The operator $B:M^\perp\to M$ is bounded, since $P$ is bounded. Of course, 
$$
M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\0\end{bmatrix}:\ x\in M\right\}. 
$$Let us determine $N$. We know that $N=(\ker P)^\perp$. And
$$
\ker P=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}:\ x+By=0 \right\}.
$$ 
This allows us to write 
$$
\ker P=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -Bz\\z\end{bmatrix}:\ z\in M^\perp\right\}.
$$ 
If $\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}\in (\ker P)^\perp$ we have, for all $z\in M^\perp$
$$
0=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -Bz\\ z\end{bmatrix} \right\rangle=\langle x,-Bz\rangle+\langle y,z\rangle=\langle -B^*x+y,z\rangle.
$$
Then $-B^*x+y\in M^{\perp\perp}=M$ (here we use that $M$ is closed). Now, since $B$ maps $M^\perp$ to $M$, its adjoint $B^*$ maps $M$ to $M^\perp$. So $-B^*x+y\in M^\perp$. As $M\cap M^\perp=\{0\}$, we get that $-B^*x+y=0$. In other words, 
$$
N=(\ker P)^\perp=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\ B^*x\end{bmatrix}:\ x\in M\right\}.
$$
Now, given $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, we have 
$$
m=\begin{bmatrix} x\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ n=\begin{bmatrix} z\\ B^*z\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $x,z\in M$. Then
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in N\setminus\{0\}}\frac{|\langle m,n\rangle|}{ \|n\|}
&=\sup_{z\in M}\frac{|\langle x,z\rangle|}{\sqrt{\|z\|^2+\|B^*z\|^2}}\\[0.3cm]
&\geq\sup_{z\in M}\frac{|\langle x,z\rangle|}{\sqrt{\|z\|^2+\|B^*\|^2\,\|z\|^2}}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\|B\|^2}}\,\sup_{z\in M}\frac{|\langle x,z\rangle|}{\|z\|}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{\|x\|}{\sqrt{1+\|B\|^2}}
=\frac{\|m\|}{\sqrt{1+\|B\|^2}}
\end{align}
(since $x\in M$, the equality $\sup_{z\in M}\frac{|\langle x,z\rangle|}{\|z\|}=\|x\|$ is an easy consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz). 
So, for any nonzero $m\in M$, 
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in N\setminus\{0\}}\frac{|\langle m,n\rangle|}{\|m\|\, \|n\|}
\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\|B\|^2}}=\frac1{\|P\|}.
\end{align}
To see this last equality, note that $$\|P\|^2=\|P^*\|=\|PP^*\|=\|I+BB^*\|=1+\|BB^*\|=1+\|B\|^2.$$

Comment: +1 This is a very slick proof!! Also, I just learned about weak and weak-$\star$ convergence and some related theorems, but I now finally see a nice application ;) Thanks!

Comment: I have one question. So we use that $(m_j)\subset \{m\in M\mid ||m||\leq 1 \}$, which is closed, convex and bounded, so weakly compact. Therefore the limit of the weakly convergent subsequence must be inside this unit ball. Now, how can we be sure that it is not $0$?

Comment: You are absolute right, that's a problem. Let me think about it.

Comment: I have edited in a completely different argument. No appeal to theorems, other than Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Why is $\|n\|=\|z\|+\sqrt{\|z\|^2+\|B^*z\|^2}$ instead of $\|n\|=\sqrt{\|z\|^2+\|B^*z\|^2}$?

Comment: Also, in that case, am I right that we can even specify the bound as $1/\|P\|$?

Comment: Typo, and yes, I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first prove the following lemma.

**Lemma**: Assume $F,G$ are closed subspaces of a Hilbert space such that $F\cap G^\perp = \{0\}$. Then there is $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $f \in F\setminus \{0\}$, $\sup_{g \in G\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\vert \langle f,g\rangle\vert}{\Vert f \Vert\cdot \Vert g \Vert}\geq \epsilon$.

**Proof**: Consider the map $\phi : F \rightarrow G^*$ sending each $f$ to the linear form $g \mapsto \langle f,g\rangle$. The map $\phi$ is anti-linear, bounded by one, and injective by our assumption.

Now, $G$ is a Hilbert space. So let us denote by $\flat$ the anti-linear map $G^* \rightarrow G$ sending any linear form $\lambda$ on $G$ to the vector $\flat(\lambda)$ such that, for every $v\in G$, $\lambda(v) = \langle \flat(\lambda),v\rangle$. We can check that $\flat \circ \phi = P_G$, where $P_G$ is the (restriction on $F$ of the) orthogonal projector on $G$. Indeed, if $f \in F$, then for every $g \in G$, $\langle f ,g \rangle = \langle P_G(f) + (f- P_G(f)),g\rangle = \langle P_G(f),g\rangle$.

The projector $P_G$ has closed range, so, since $\flat$ is an (anti-linear) isomorphism, $\phi$ has a closed range too. So the co-restriction $\phi : F \rightarrow \phi(F)$ is a bounded, bijective anti-linear operator between Hilbert spaces, so by the Banach isomorphism theorem, its inverse is continuous. So $\phi$ is bounded below, that is, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $f \in F$, $\Vert \phi(f)\Vert \geq \epsilon \Vert f \Vert$. Now, $\Vert \phi(f)\Vert = \sup_{g \in G\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\vert \langle f,g\rangle\vert}{\Vert g \Vert}$ so we are done.

Now, in your setting, if you assume that $P$ is nonzero, then $M \cap N^\perp = im(P) \cap \ker(P) = \{0\}$, so you can just apply the lemma to $M = F$ and $N = G$.

Comment: $\phi$ is already defined and I just defined $\flat$.

Comment: +1, but instead of quoting some lecture notes, you could say that $\phi$ is a bounded bijection onto its image, so it is invertible by the Open Mapping Theorem (or you can quote the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: Ok I changed my answer according to your comments.

Comment: If you don't see why, then it's not trivial :p

Comment: @rae306: The map $\phi$ takes $f$ to a linear functional in $G^*$. And $\flat$ take a functional in $G^*$ to the element of $G$ that corresponds to it via the Riesz Representation Theorem. So you have, if $h=\flat(\phi(f))$, that 
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\langle h,g\rangle
$$
for all $g\in G$. Then, for any $z$,
$$
\langle P_Gf,z\rangle=\langle f,P_Gz\rangle = \langle h,P_Gz\rangle =\langle P_Gh,z\rangle=\langle h,z\rangle.
$$
This implies $P_Gf=h$.

Comment: @Plop this is a very slick proof! Thanks for adding the additional details needed for me to understand the proof. I had to read the whole proof 6 times but I finally understand it. Thanks!

Comment: (I am removing the unneeded comments.)